# mingw+libarchive: cross compiling linker error

Tags: c, linker, mingw, libarchive

I'm trying to cross compile a tiny program under Linux for win32. It uses libarchive, which is available in for mingw on my fedora 23 installation (all installed through dnf), but I get lots of linker errors.

Source: https://github.com/panzi/save_the_zazus

Compiler/linker output:

```
panzi@panzi save_the_zazus [master*]$ mkdir -p package/img
panzi@panzi save_the_zazus [master*]$ touch package/img/atlas0.png package/img/atlas1.png package/img/atlas2.png
panzi@panzi save_the_zazus [master*]$ make TARGET=win32 setup
mkdir -p build/win32 build/src
panzi@panzi save_the_zazus [master*]$ make TARGET=win32
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -m32 -DLIBARCHIVE_STATIC -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu11 -Ibuild/src -O2 -c src/save_the_zazus.c -o build/win32/save_the_zazus.o
xxd -i package/img/atlas0.png > build/src/package_img_atlas0_png.c
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -m32 -DLIBARCHIVE_STATIC -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu11 -Ibuild/src -O2 -c build/src/package_img_atlas0_png.c -o build/win32/package_img_atlas0_png.o
xxd -i package/img/atlas1.png > build/src/package_img_atlas1_png.c
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -m32 -DLIBARCHIVE_STATIC -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu11 -Ibuild/src -O2 -c build/src/package_img_atlas1_png.c -o build/win32/package_img_atlas1_png.o
xxd -i package/img/atlas2.png > build/src/package_img_atlas2_png.c
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -m32 -DLIBARCHIVE_STATIC -Wall -Werror -Wextra -std=gnu11 -Ibuild/src -O2 -c build/src/package_img_atlas2_png.c -o build/win32/package_img_atlas2_png.o
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -m32 -DLIBARCHIVE_STATIC -static -larchive build/win32/save_the_zazus.o build/win32/package_img_atlas0_png.o build/win32/package_img_atlas1_png.o build/win32/package_img_atlas2_png.o -o build/win32/save_the_zazus.exe
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x301): undefined reference to `archive_read_new'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x31d): undefined reference to `archive_read_support_filter_all'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x3cd): undefined reference to `archive_entry_free'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x3df): undefined reference to `archive_read_free'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x3ef): undefined reference to `archive_write_free'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x426): undefined reference to `archive_error_string'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x462): undefined reference to `archive_error_string'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x4a1): undefined reference to `archive_read_support_format_all'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x538): undefined reference to `archive_read_open_filename'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x545): undefined reference to `archive_write_new'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x557): undefined reference to `archive_write_set_format_zip'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x56b): undefined reference to `archive_write_set_options'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x581): undefined reference to `archive_error_string'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x5c9): undefined reference to `archive_write_open_filename'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x5d9): undefined reference to `archive_error_string'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x61e): undefined reference to `archive_error_string'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x67a): undefined reference to `archive_entry_new2'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x6ba): undefined reference to `archive_read_next_header2'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x6d0): undefined reference to `archive_entry_pathname'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x727): undefined reference to `archive_entry_new2'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x73d): undefined reference to `archive_entry_copy_pathname'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x74b): undefined reference to `archive_entry_perm'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x75a): undefined reference to `archive_entry_set_perm'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x762): undefined reference to `archive_entry_filetype'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x771): undefined reference to `archive_entry_set_filetype'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x77f): undefined reference to `archive_entry_mode'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x78e): undefined reference to `archive_entry_set_mode'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x7a5): undefined reference to `archive_entry_set_size'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x7b3): undefined reference to `archive_entry_uid'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x7c3): undefined reference to `archive_entry_set_uid'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x7d1): undefined reference to `archive_entry_gid'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x7e1): undefined reference to `archive_entry_set_gid'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x7ef): undefined reference to `archive_entry_mtime_nsec'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x803): undefined reference to `archive_entry_mtime'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x819): undefined reference to `archive_entry_set_mtime'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x82b): undefined reference to `archive_write_header'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x83b): undefined reference to `archive_entry_free'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x854): undefined reference to `archive_write_data'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x870): undefined reference to `archive_error_string'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x904): undefined reference to `archive_write_header'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x91a): undefined reference to `archive_entry_size'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x948): undefined reference to `archive_read_data'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x96c): undefined reference to `archive_write_data'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x988): undefined reference to `archive_error_string'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0x9dd): undefined reference to `archive_write_add_filter_none'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0xa13): undefined reference to `archive_error_string'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0xa47): undefined reference to `archive_entry_free'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0xa8e): undefined reference to `archive_error_string'
build/win32/save_the_zazus.o:save_the_zazus.c:(.text.startup+0xad6): undefined reference to `archive_error_string'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'build/win32/save_the_zazus.exe' failed
make: *** [build/win32/save_the_zazus.exe] Error 1
```

For this single source file program I just wrote a simple Makefile. The png files aren't in the repo (yet), so just create empty files for them if you try to compile. I tried dynamic and static linking (would prefer static so all I need to do is to pass on a .exe file). For this output I used `-static -larchive` and it doesn't complain about any missing libraries, but I get all those undefined references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-static -larchive` to the end of your command line and try again.  The linker isn't getting the library to link against.  I've found it needs to be last on the command line.

Comment: That was it. Also I had to add all the dependencies of libarchive.